# CRM 2011 Import Wizard changing date format?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have been trying to import contacts from a .csv file into CRM 2011.

All seems well until I look at the failures and see any contacts I am trying to import with a date of birth are failing.

I have checked both my settings and the system settings and they are both set to English (UK). The .csv file originally had the dob in the following format dd/mm/yyyy but after the import it looks like this has been changed to mm/dd/yyyy which is why it is failing (seems impossible but I have tried this a number of times).

Any ideas how I can ensure that the date format does not change so that I can successfully import my contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but i think it may work:

1. Open the csv file in Excel
2. Set the format of the DOB column to your preferred date format.
3. Save the file in Excel 2003 xml format.
4. Import the new xml file

Comment: Thank you Bojan - I did use the xml format instead and it worked perfectly